# Using if else in fileoutput.writelines() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use if and else commands while using writelines(), here  is my code

```
mylist=[7,4,3,6,7,8]
fileoutput=open('data.txt','w')
fileoutput.writelines("%s\t" % mylist[place] for place in range(6) if place !=5 else "%s\n" % mylist[place] )
fileoutput.close()
```

But an SyntaxError (SyntaxError: invalid syntax) appears.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't call your variable list, as that is also the built-in type `list`

Comment: @LuisAFK yeah, yourright, I change it to 'mylist', but I still have the previous problem ...

Comment: What is the expression (?) inside the write lines supposed to do? It looks like a mash-up between generator expression (a for and if but not else) and conditional expression (an if and else but not for).

Comment: If I remove if else statements and write fileoutput.writelines('\n') at the line before fileoutput.close(), the lines will be written while having a 'tab' at the end, I dont want the 'tab'

Comment: So you don't actually want to write lines, you want to write the values joined by tabs, with a single newline at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First problem, you call your variable `list`, like the built-in type `list`.
2. You call `fileoutput.open()`, but `fileoutput` doesn't exist. Instead, what you want to do would be `fileoutput = open('data.txt','w')`
3. The order in which you're doing the `if else` statements is wrong. It should be `"%s\t" % mylist[place] if place !=5 else "%s\n" % mylist[place] for place in range(6)`

So the final code should be:

```
mylist=[7,4,3,6,7,8]
fileoutput = open('data.txt','w')
fileoutput.writelines("%s\t" % mylist[place] if place !=5 else "%s\n" % mylist[place] for place in range(6))
fileoutput.close()
```

and the output in `data.txt` would be:

```
7   4   3   6   7   8
```

with a newline at the end.